# How to receive MouseMove or ManipulationDelta events from a LongListSelector in Windows Phone 7 and/or 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, touch-event, longlistselector

If I have a grid on a normal page I can do the following and the event handler is called numerous times.

```
<Grid ManipulationDelta="My_ManipulationDelta" />
```

If instead, I add it to a longlistselector, it's called few times and the value is usually the same each time

```
<phone:LongListSelector ManipulationDelta="My_ManipulationDelta" />
```

I've also tried adding it to the itemtemplate, which had the same results:

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock
             ManipulationDelta="TextBlock_ManipulationDelta"
             Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there a work around or another event or some part of the LongListSelector that can give me information about touch movements of the user - specifically movement along the Y-axis?

Comment: try to listen to `ManipulationDelta` event of LongListSelector's Item instead of LLS it self.

Comment: I've added it to the itemtemplate but it's still is only seldom rasied.

Answer (score 0):

If ManipulationDelta="My_ManipulationDelta" doesn't work correct, you can try **GestureListener**.

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    ...
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

But it shows only delta between the event raises.